# What does it mean to invoke `make -f` with a target that appears to be setting a variable? (And why isn't it working for me?)

Tags: linux, makefile, sh

## Summary

I am trying to understand a complicated chain of Makefiles, in order to get a build to succeed. I narrowed down my problem to this bit in our build script:

```
INF_RL=`make -f $BUILD_ROOT/Makefile BUILD_ROOT_MAKEFILE= show__BUILD_INF_RL`
$INF_RL/$BUILD_UTILS_RELDIR/BuildAll.sh
```

`$INF_RL` is being set to an empty string (or not being set). If I replace the first line with

```
INF_RL=/foo_rel_linx86/infrastructure_release/v8.0.14
```

in order to hardcode what I know `$INF_RL` is supposed to be, then the build goes smoothly. But I want to know how to fix this the proper way.

## What I've Tried / Thought

My first thought was that `make -f` is failing. So I tried it in my shell:

```
% make -f $BUILD_ROOT/Makefile BUILD_ROOT_MAKEFILE= show__BUILD_INF_RL

% setenv | grep BUILD_ROOT
BUILD_ROOT=/userhome/andrew.cheong/TPS
```

Indeed, it returned an empty string. But what conclusion could I draw from this? I wasn't sure if the shell was the same thing as the environment / scope in which Make was chaining together its Makefiles. I abandoned this investigation.

---

Next, I looked into `show__BUILD_INF_RL`, which seemed to be defined in `$BUILD_ROOT/Makefile`:

```
BUILD_ROOT_MAKEFILE = 1

MAKE_DIRS = src

CASE_KITS = tpsIn tpsOut

REQUIRED_VERSIONS = "case.v$(INF_VS)"

all:

## These next 3 rules allows any variable set in this makefile (and therefore
## the included makefile.include to have it's value echoed from the command
## "make show_<variableName>"
## NOTE: the "disp" target is vital as it allows the show_% implicit rule to be
##       recognised as such - implicit rules *must* have a target.

show_% := DISPLAY_MACRO = $(@:show_%=%)

show_% : disp
    @ echo $($(DISPLAY_MACRO))

disp:

include $(BUILD_ROOT)/makefile.include
```

Here, I faced more questions:

1. What is `BUILD_ROOT_MAKEFILE` for? Why is it set to `1`, then seemingly something else in the `make -f` command?
2. In the `make -f` command, is `BUILD_ROOT_MAKEFILE=` its own argument? If so, what kind of target or rule is that? Otherwise, why is it being set to the macro?

---

In `$BUILD_ROOT`, there is another file, `makefile.LINUX_X86.include`:

```
BUILD_INF_RL = /foo_rel_linx86/infrastructure_release/v$(INF_VS)
$(warning $(BUILD_INF_RL))
BUILD_UTILS  = $(BUILD_INF_RL)/build-utils_LINUX_X86
```

Though a completely ignorant guess, I think `BUILD_INF_RL` is being set here, and intended to be extracted into the build script's variable `INF_RL` when the macro `show__BUILD_INF_RL` is invoked. I added the middle line to see if it was indeed being set, and indeed, I get this output when running the build script:

```
/userhome/andrew.cheong/TPS/makefile.LINUX_X86.include:3: /foo_rel_linx86/infrastructure_release/v8.0.14
```

*i.e.* Looks like what I've hardcoded way above! But why doesn't it make it into `INF_RL`? There is yet another file, `makefile.include`, also in `$BUILD_ROOT`:

```
#
# INCLUDE THIS FILE AS THE LAST LINE IN THE LOCAL MAKEFILE
#
# makefile.include - use this file to define global build settings
# e.g. infrastructure version and location, or third-party
#
# supported macros in addition to build-utils-makefile.include
#
# BUILD_INF_RL  : optional, specification of infrastructure release location
#                 defaults to vdev_build area
#

include $(BUILD_ROOT)/../../makefile.include.$(BUILD_ARCH).Versions

#include $(BUILD_UTILS)/makefile.archdef.include
include $(BUILD_ROOT)/makefile.$(BUILD_ARCH).include

$(warning $(BUILD_INF_RL))

_BUILD_INF_RL = $(BUILD_INF_RL)

# place the results at the root of the infdemo tree
BUILD_DEST = $(BUILD_ROOT)

INCLUDE_DIRS += $(BUILD_INF_RL)/core/$(BUILD_TARGET)/include

LINK_DIRS += $(BUILD_INF_RL)/core/$(BUILD_TARGET)/lib

# libraries required for a typical fidessa app, including OA and DB access
FIDEVMAPP_LIBS = FidApp FidInf FidCore Fidevm

include $(BUILD_UTILS)/makefile.include
```

That `$(warning ...)` is again mine, and when running the build script, I get:

```
/userhome/andrew.cheong/TPS/makefile.include:18: /foo_rel_linx86/infrastructure_release/v8.0.14
```

## The Question

The fact that both `$(warning ...)`s show up when I run the build script that's calling the `make -f ... show__BUILD_INF_RL`, tells me that those Makefiles *are* being included. Then what is causing the macro to fail and return an empty string instead of the correct `INF_RL` path?

---

#### Historical Notes

<sup>These build scripts were written at a time when we were only compiling for Solaris. (The scripts were based on templates written by an infrastructure team that loosely accounted for both Solaris and Linux, but we never ran the Linux branch, as it was unnecessary.) We are now fully migrating to Linux, and hitting this issue. The reason I'm skeptical of it being a Linux versus Solaris issue is that we have at least four other products that use a similar Makefile chain and have been migrated with no issues. Not sure why this one in particular is behaving different.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question got very long and complex so I didn't read it all... for SO it's often better if you just ask a specific targeted question that you want to know the answer to, with a simple repro case.

I can't say why different makefiles behave differently, but this line:

```
show_% := DISPLAY_MACRO = $(@:show_%=%)
```

seems really wrong to me.  This is (a) setting the variable `show_%`, which don't actually use anywhere, (b) to the simply expanded string `DISPLAY_MACRO =` because at this point in the makefile the variable `$@` is not set to any value.

Maybe you wanted this line to be this instead:

```
show_% : DISPLAY_MACRO = $(@:show_%=%)
```

(note `:` not `:=`) so that it's a pattern-specific variable assignment, not a simple variable assignment?

Comment: You nailed it! Yeah, sorry about the long question, but when dealing with such large and sprawled out company infrastructure code from the 90s, it becomes impossible to reduce things to a "simple repro case." I mean suppose did manage to "reproduce" the issue, which is that `INF_RL` was not set—How would I even know whether in my cutting out of thousands of lines of code (the builds script is several thousands), I did something _else_ to clear out `INF_RL`? The way I asked my question was the best I could do given so many unknowns.